# MySQL Unique Key scenario

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that is consisted of the following columns:

*Table name:* **User**

*Columns:* {id, fk1, fk2, username}

**id**: is the primary key

**fk1** and **fk2** are foreign keys coming from other tables

There are 2 cases:

1) fk1 + username = unique value

2) fk2 + username = unique value

For example:

fk1 = the **id** of a country in the country table

fk2 = the **id** of a state in the state table

**In countries that have states (ex. USA)**

What i want is the username of the user to be only unique inside a state. Two users from different states can have the same username, but not in the same state.

**In countries with no states (ex. Spain)**

Two users from the same country cannot have the same username. Two users from different countries can have the same username.

So, if the user registered is coming from a country having states i need to create a unique index for columns **fk2** and **username**. [ensure uniqueness per state]

If the user registered is coming from a country with no states i need to create a unique index for columns **fk1** and **username**. [ensure uniqueness per country]

What i did so far was to create a table for users coming from states and a table for users coming from a country with no states. Like below:

--Table name: **User_States**

Columns: {id, fk2, username}

Unique index on fk2 + username

--Table name: **User**

Columns: {id, fk1, username}

Unique index on fk1 + username

This solution can work by filtering the users (users from state or not) before inserting the data into each table. But i want only one table with all users and not two, because when i want to check if for example an email is already registered by a user (either in states or not) i have to perform 2 queries (one in each table). Or if i want to extract a list of all usernames like "darklord", regardless of their location, again i have to perform 2 queries.

Is there a way to have this? If yes, how will the table look like? My problem starts when the user comes from a country with no states, since the **fk2** column is going to be empty.  I know that a unique index allows Null value but only one Null value.

Also one general question: How can i check if a single query on a big table is faster/slower than 2 queries on 2 smaller tables?

PS: The storage engine i am using is InnoDB

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why in the world would you allow this type of quasi-unique username? When a person logs in do they have to enter their username, password and location information? What would happen if you had 2 people with the same username and the same password? Which one is it? This is why usernames are unique.

Comment: The "username" is just an example - and maybe a bad one. Just try to think it as a data field that more than one users can have the same value but linked with fk1 or fk2 to be unique as described above.

Comment: Can you have a single table to hold these values instead of multiple tables? Then you could use a unique constraint on multiple columns.

Comment: The reason for splitting the table into Country table and State table is to satisfy (to a point) the normalization. Imagine a if i have 10.000 users from Spain.. The word "Spain" will be repeated 10.000 in my database..

Comment: Not if you properly normalize your data. You should have a Countries table and you would store the CountryCode (if using natural keys) or the identity value (if using surrogate keys) in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this work?

```
create table #Something
(
    SomeDataField varchar(10) not null,
    CountryCode char(3) not null,
    StateCode char(2) null,
    CONSTRAINT UniqueCountryState UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        SomeDataField, CountryCode, StateCode
    )
)

insert #Something
select 'Value1', 'USA', 'NY' union all
select 'Value1', 'CAN', null union all
select 'Value1', 'MEX', null union all
select 'Value1', 'USA', 'AK'
```

Now try inserting any of those values again and it will fail because the combination already exists.

```
insert #Something
select 'Value1', 'USA', 'NY'
```

Comment: I will give it a try tonight and let you know. What i am trying to limit with the use of unique index, i can limit it with the a PHP script on server side. The reason i need the unique key is for faster data searching..

Comment: I would STRONGLY recommend that you do not leave referential integrity to the application. There is nothing wrong with using the application to help but removing it from the database is a recipe for disaster. btw, I don't know if the code I posted will work for you because you are using InnoDB and the code I posted is sql server. I don't know anything about InnoDB.

Comment: And a unique key is not required for faster searching. A unique constraint will generate an index behind the scenes which is what will help your performance when querying the data. You can add an index without the need for a unique constraint.

Comment: Dont worry. What i need is just the idea behind it and i will make it work in MySQL as well.

Comment: Thinking aloud, what if in the case of a non state user, i added fk2 = 0 [or fk2 DEFAULT VALUE '0'] and then created only one unique index on fk1+fk2+SomeDataField? This way the unique key should always be unique for both cases. And in the case of a state user to insert the corresponding fk2.If New York has the id of 2, then fk2=2, USA has the id of 6, then fk1=6 then its going to to insert 6 1 SomeData.

Comment: In that scenario how would deal with USA (value of 6) and whatever state has a value of 6? The unique check would fail but it is because you are using a single column to represent values from multiple locations.

Comment: The country is represented by fk1. The state is represented by fk2. And the data is represented by SomeData. So if USA has fk1 = 6, California has fk2=6 and SomeDate = 'SeanLange', then no other SeanLange from USA, California will be permitted to be inserted in the database since the unique key 66SeanLange wont permit it.

Comment: LOL. What you are describing is what I meant to post as the unique constraint in my code. It should have included SomeDataField but did not. I will fix that. :D